# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Comparison method violates its general contract! in Collections#sort

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

What can be reason of this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:426)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:223)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
        ...
```

i use comparator like this:

```
private Comparator<SomeObject> comporator = new Comparator<SomeObject>() {
    public int compare(SomeObject o1, SomeObject o2) {
        return Double.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue());
    }
};

public double getValue() {
    double value = 0;
    for (Parameter parameter : parametrs()) {
        value = value + (parameter.getWeight() * parameter.getSomeValue(this));
    }
    return value;//20.0, 23.0 ...
}
```

where parameter.getSomeValue:

```
public int getSomeValue(SomeObject process) {
    return (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - process.getPutTime()) / 1000);
}
```

in:

```
public void sort() {
    synchronized (list) {
        Collections.sort(list, comporator);
    }
}
```

where:

```
List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
```

I can't reproduce this exception, but it arises sometimes.
Also, can you give code example where this issue appear in 100% of cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compare method compares two objects based on the value returned by `getValue()`. Since that value may change in consecutive calls to that method for the same object, this may lead to inconsistencies. It seems the value depends on time, which is a bad idea.

Suppose you compare object1 to object2 and find out that `compare(object1, object2) < 0`. Now, you compare object2 to object1 and find out that `compare(object2, object1) < 0`. This violates the contract of the compare method, since an object can't be both smaller and larger than another object. Since each call to your `getValue` gives a different result, that seems to increase with time, the object got which `getValue` was called later may have a higher `getValue()` if all the other parameters that determine `getValue()` are equal in the two objects.